# Updating only selected features with the QGIS Gaphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, features, qgis-modeler, select-by-location, update

I want to update selected features (features within a specific buffer or selected with their attributes) with the graphical modeller of QGIS but It doesn't work because I don't find the algorithm in the list when I use the algorithm Field Calculator in the next step of my processing.

It only works with the algorithm that extracts features.

Comment: Hi Vincent Linlaud, Welcome to GIS SE. Question is unclear. There is an algorithm `Select by expression`, `Select by attribute`, `Select by Location` and `Select within Distance`, all available in the modeler. What is the problem? Please edit and update the question, otherwise it risks to be closed.

Comment: You are selecting features outside the model, then executing it?

Comment: I know these algorithms but I can't find them as "algorithm exit" when I want to use the "Field calculator" only for selected features in my processing...